# Grails spring-security-ldap without user/role in database

Tags: grails, ldap, spring-security

I am looking for a Spring Security LDAP tuturial.

The few tutorials I have found all seem to create a user/roles domain classes.

What I want is to use the controllers etc.. But since I'm integrating with LDAP I really don't want to create user and roles tables in my database. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're more or less required to create the User and Role domains, start by reading here: [Simplified Spring Security](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) also check out the screen casts, they explain how things work.

Comment: The LDAP plugin has it's own user objects that it uses, so no extra domain clutter is needed.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to have the LDAP configuration set correctly in `config.groovy` (assuming you have the login / logout views / controllers it expects.

What I did was to run the "normal" s2 script to initialize spring security core, and then removed the classes and config values it added. Then, added my LDAP config info and it all just worked.

If you want anything more than to simply authenticate against LDAP using the LDAP group membership as roles, you will need more, but for just users and roles, nothing extra is needed other than the pugins and some configs.